# add member to object, creating it first if nonexistent

Tags: json, jq

I want to add a key-value pair to a JSON using jq, but it also needs to add the parent if that doesn't exists. An example:

```
{
  "notebook_task": {
    "notebook_path": "/Applications/dbtest/addcol",
    "base_parameters": {           
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want it to look like this:

```
{
  "notebook_task": {
    "notebook_path": "/Applications/dbtest/addcol",
    "base_parameters": {
        "app_name": "testapp"
    }
  }
}
```

The key **'base_parameters'** might not exist. I already tried the following, but without success:

```
jq '. |= .notebook_task | if has("base_parameters") then .base_parameters + { "app_name": "testapp" } else . + { "base_parameters": {"app_name": "testapp"} } end'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's certain that the key `base_parameters` is either nonexistent or has an object value, simply assigning a value to `.base_parameters.app_name` will just work.

```
.notebook_task.base_parameters.app_name = "testapp"
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yHTNEY1JVZ)</sup>